# how to check if a value is greater than all other values in alist by a certain value in python

Tags: python-3.6

do any of you know if there are any ways for me to check if a value is greater than all other values in a list by a certain value in python?Thanks
Here's my code which unfortunately doesn't work:

```
a=[2,4,6,7,21]
print(a)
x=int(input("Enter a value:"))
if x-a>=1:
 print("The value inputted is has a difference of at least one with all the      other values in list a.")
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Try the following :

```
def isGreater(a_value, an_array, min_diff):
  res = True
  if (not all(x <= a_value - min_diff for x in an_array)):
    res = False
  return res

a = [1, 5, 3, 2, 7]
an_input = int(input("Enter a number: "))

print(isGreater(an_input, a, 1))
```

Comment: well because like i want to check if it's greater by a certain number then print true.For example if x is more than all the list elements by 1.Sorry for the trouble and thank you very much.

Comment: @NathanLeow Okay so you can print what the function returns, as I edited